# Visiting a rails page throws an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a page which shows a list of images and the amount of points added to that image. Locally it works fine, but now I'm trying to get it to work on my server and when I visit the page I get an error,

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.
>   If you are the application owner check the logs for more information

My log shows this,

```
I, [2015-02-03T06:51:31.352333 #28417]  INFO -- : Started GET "/competitions/4" for 82.73.170.71 at 2015-02-03 06:51:31 -0500
I, [2015-02-03T06:51:31.353823 #28417]  INFO -- : Processing by CompetitionsController#show as HTML
I, [2015-02-03T06:51:31.353886 #28417]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"id"=>"4"}
I, [2015-02-03T06:51:31.364301 #28417]  INFO -- :   Rendered competitions/show.html.haml within layouts/application (7.8ms)
I, [2015-02-03T06:51:31.364563 #28417]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms
F, [2015-02-03T06:51:31.366172 #28417] FATAL -- :
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `points' for #<Picture:0x007f80f61ca038>):
    54:               Votes
    55:               - if signed_in?
    56:                 - if current_user == @competition.user || current_user.administrator? || Time.now.in_time_zone("Amsterdam") <= @competition.deadline
    57:                   = picture.points
    58:                   -# = pluralize(picture.votes.count, "vote" )
    59:                   -# %span
    60:                     -# %div
  app/views/competitions/show.html.haml:57:in `block in _app_views_competitions_show_html_haml___3029568455364587805_70095924335640'
  app/views/competitions/show.html.haml:44:in `each'
  app/views/competitions/show.html.haml:44:in `_app_views_competitions_show_html_haml___3029568455364587805_70095924335640'
```

the code from my show.html.haml

```
- if Time.now.in_time_zone("Amsterdam") >= @competition.deadline_signin
      - @competition.pictures.shuffle.each do |picture|
        .item
          = link_to picture do
            = image_tag(picture.image_url)
          .content
            %p
              Door:
              = picture.user.name

            %p.vote
              Votes
              - if signed_in?
                - if current_user == @competition.user || current_user.administrator? || Time.now.in_time_zone("Amsterdam") <= @competition.deadline
                  = picture.points
                  -# = pluralize(picture.votes.count, "vote" )
                  -# %span
                    -# %div
                      -# %p
                        -# \ #{pluralize(picture.votes.count, "" )}
            = link_to picture.title, picture, :class => "art-name"
```

Does anyone see what the problem might be?

> edit "showing migration"

`20150131130944_add_points_to_pictures.rb`

```
class AddPointsToPictures < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :pictures, :points, :integer, default: 0
  end
end
```

And the migration action,

```
deploy@appsynt:~/wisemonkeys/current$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate
==  AddPositionToPictures: migrating ==========================================
-- add_column(:pictures, :position, :integer)
   -> 0.0046s
==  AddPositionToPictures: migrated (0.0049s) =================================

==  AddPointsToPictures: migrating ============================================
-- add_column(:pictures, :points, :integer, {:default=>0})
   -> 0.0034s
==  AddPointsToPictures: migrated (0.0037s) ===================================
```

Comment: Does Picture actually have a points method?

Comment: If points is an attribute you added with a migration, be sure to run migrations on the server.

Comment: Have you tried messing with that method in your production Rails Console?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add points on Picture controller at permit (Rails 4)

Or

In Picture model attr_accessible (Rails3)

Comment: Hm, not sure what I did to fix it, but it seems to be working now. I think my database file didn't get updated with my migrate action. I dropped my DB and migrated, and now the error is gone.